# How to encrypt a file with openpgp PGPy - Django python

Tags: python, django, encryption, pgp, openpgp

I am trying to use PGPy for encrypt a zip file.

I had a public and private key, but it seems going to dead-end as PGPy decline my keys due to missing required flags..

I already try to bypass require flag as guided from the documentation and still error happen. Also, I sent an issue to its github https://github.com/SecurityInnovation/PGPy/issues/382

Could someone assist me the simple way to perform this? Or maybe there is another way to achieve this?

Any positive feedback will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most common OpenPGP keys consists of sign-only primary key with bounded encrypt-only subkeys. And in most cases you would not be able to encrypt to the primary key (as it would be DSA or EdDSA/ECDSA key which only allows to sign and verify messages).
Most likely you should use `subkeys` property of the `PGPKey` object to select an appropriate subkey.